# installing KnowRob

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I tried to install KnowRob package (http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:_KnowRob_basics) but got some errors. First I check the two repositories.
git clone http://code.in.tum.de/git/ias-common.git
svn co http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest

everything was fine

than using http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:_KnowRob_basics
tried to satisfy the system dependences
rosdep satisfy knowrob

Got the error. rosdep: command not found

After that tried to do
sudo apt-get install [...] # only if something is missing

And got lots error massages like this

ine1.2: Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
kdebase-runtime but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: winetricks but it is not installable
Recommends: wisotool but it is not installable
Conflicts: wine1.0 but 1.0.1-0ubuntu13 is to be installed
wine1.2-dev: Conflicts: wine1.0-dev but 1.0.1-0ubuntu13 is to be installed
wine1.2-gecko: Conflicts: wine1.0-gecko but 0.1.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
wmppp.app: Depends: ppp but it is not going to be installed
wx2.6-i18n: Conflicts: wx-i18n
wx2.8-i18n: Conflicts: wx-i18n
E: Broken packages

So finally with executing the make command I got this errors

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building stack ['KnowRob']
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['KnowRob']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/bojan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120814-103359
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['KnowRob'] to:
['srldb', 'comp_temporal', 'knowrob_omics', 'jpl', 'thea', 'knowrob_actions', 'mod_probcog', 'comp_orgprinciples', 'knowrob_objects', 'semweb', 'mod_srdl', 'comp_spatial', 'bosch_semantic_map', 'ias_prolog_addons', 'ias_semantic_map', 'knowrob_cad_models', 'knowrob_common', 'navp_action', 'annotation_srvs', 'vision_srvs', 'triangle_mesh_msgs', 'ias_table_msgs', 'cogman_msgs', 'vision_msgs', 'tf_prolog', 'mod_vis', 'comp_cop', 'rosprolog', 'json_prolog', 'comp_germandeli', 'ias_knowledge_base', 'knowrob_cad_parser']
cannot find required resource: client_rosjava_jni

Any help???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41321/installing-knowrob/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-14**:
Please tag your question correctly, i.e. add the tag knowrob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, it's good practice to fix the first error first, in this case the "rosdep: command not found". Google or the ROS wiki search will give you instructions how to install rosdep (e.g. http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep).

The line "sudo apt-get install [...] # only if something is missing" was not intended to be typed in literally, but means that you should install those packages that rosdep reported as missing.

Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-14**:
ok. Thanks. Works now

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-08-14**:
Can you then please mark the question as 'answered'? (or rather mark the answer as 'correct')